# Put alert on top of main div

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app my flash alerts dont display correctly :
[image]

I have tried to put a z-index on my alert class but it doesnt work. Here's the way I organize my code in the app. I render the alerts in the layout :

```
  <%= render 'shared/navbar'%>
 <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
```

and here's my html in slim for the flashes :

```
- if notice
  div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" id="alert" role="alert"
    div class="container"
      div class="row"
        div class="col-xs-12"
          button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
            span aria-hidden="true" &times;
          = notice.html_safe

- if alert
    div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" id="alert" role="alert"
      div class="container"
        div class="row"
          div class="col-xs-12"
            button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
              span aria-hidden="true" &times;
            = alert.html_safe
```

maybe I should also change my class background-cover which wraps my home page that you see ?

```
.background-cover {
  background-position: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%), image-url("hands.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 661px;
}
```

Here's my home page html :

```
<div class="background-cover">
  <div class="row text-center quickbed">
    <h1 class="title">Quickbed</h1>
    <p class="punchline">Se sentir chez soi est un droit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row options">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card card-block  text-center">
        <h3 class="card-title option-title ">Hotel d'hébergement social</h3>
        <p class="card-text">Par ici si vous souhaitez accueillir des réfugiés.</p>
        <%= link_to "S'inscrire", "#", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg js-subscription-form" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card card-block text-center">
        <h3 class="card-title option-title">Association volontaire</h3>
        <p class="card-text">Par ici si vous faites parti d'une association aidant les réfugiés à trouver un logement.</p>
        <%= link_to "S'inscrire", "#", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg js-subscription-form" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="row" id="story">
    <h2 class= "text-center">Why Quickbed ?</h2>
    <h3 class="text-center"> For you Super helper</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Find quickly a bed</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Find Cheapest price</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Manage your bills easily</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <h3 class="text-center"> For you nice host</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Simplify your process</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Manage your team</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Optimise your space</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="subscription_form">

    <h3 class="text-center">Soyez premier à tester !</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4">
      <%= simple_form_for @user, url: users_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :first_name, label: "Prénom", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Jean"%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :last_name, label: "Nom", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Dupond" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :email, label: "Email", class: "form-control", placeholder: "dupond@gmail.com" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :organisation, label: "Organisation", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Samu Social" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :organisation_type, label: "Type d'Organisation", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit "Valider", class: "btn large_btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
      <% end -%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you show me how to make the alert come on top of the main div and explain how to do that.

Comment: You need to add the code showing the complete HTML so that we know how HTML is structured to suggest you a solution.

Comment: What CSS have you added on the alert?

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura I added the full page html

Comment: @ArtOfCode dont have any special css on the alert, I use bootstrap, I tried adding z-index to the alert class at one point but it didnt work

Comment: @DavidGeismar when you say you want the alerts in 'main div' what is a main div? I don't see any div with class `main`

Comment: sorry @SriVishnuTotakura what I meant is that right now the alert div is pushing the rest of the blocks in the page under. What I would like is the alert div superimposed on the background but still at the top of the page and under the navbar as it is now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the alert div to not push the other divs down, you might wanna add `position: absolute` CSS property to the alert divisions.

add this to your CSS

```
.alert {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px; // Should be same as the height of the header
  width: 100%;
}
```

The `top` property in the CSS above defines how far from the top of the screen will this div be added. So, if you want these alerts to be shown below the header, you will need to make it the same value as the header's height (Height + Bottom margin if any).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an absolute positioning to each flash alert element you have, i.e.

```
position: absolute;
```

in your CSS file.